# Sending Https Request But Not Getting Response

Tags: java, android, mysql, http, https

I am sending Https request to mysql server but not getting the response while performing the same task on localhost it is working. I have no experience using Https, please give me solution and explain difference between Http and Https request sending to mysql server, hope someone help me thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String emailSend = params[0];
                String tokenSend = params[1];
                String deviceIdSend = params[2];
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailSend));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", tokenSend));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", deviceIdSend));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xyz/xyz/xyz.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String resultN) {
                super.onPostExecute(resultN);
                String s = resultN.trim();
                //dialog.dismiss();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    if (result.contains("Pass")) {
```

Comment: try to make a `http` not `https` there is a lot of problems using https and didn't get an explanation

Comment: you need to write your certificate for https connection. also use this client: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: tru to run url from postman client

Comment: I am also facing this issue @Nenco can you explain it

Comment: this article explains everything you need to know: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: @Nenco I already gone through it but not much helpful for me, if you face this problem and find solution then please share the steps. I am sending https request using  DefaultHttpClient. I search on google and gone through many examples but not work for me.

Comment: Trying hard but not getting any solution to this problem.

Comment: https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/certificate-public-key-pinning-in-android-using-retrofit-2-0-74140800025b

Comment: this is the tutorial that I followed to solve this problem, check it out.

Comment: @Nenco The tutorial was good and well explained but i dont thing it is safe to use other libraries.

Comment: it doesn't matter what you or I think. If Google uses something who are we to say that this is "not safe" :) ? You gotta change your mindset regarding libraries, they are not unsafe :)